Using ResNet50 with SE block on imbalanced data - pytorch
I worked with a breast cancer ultrasound image dataset containing 432 benign cases, 210 malignant cases, and 133 normal cases. Initially, I used a pretrained ResNet-50 model, which yielded the following results:

Test F1 Scores: Class 0 (Benign): 0.53, Class 1 (Malignant): 0.67, Class 2 (Normal): 0.80
Test Macro F1 Score: 0.6652

These scores indicate moderate performance, which is understandable given the relatively small sample size, limiting the model’s effectiveness. I then came across an article discussing how integrating a Squeeze-and-Excitation (SE) block into ResNet-50 can enhance its performance, so I decided to give it a try.

transform_my_train = T.Compose([
    T.Resize(256),
    T.CenterCrop(224),
    T.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        T.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
transform_my=T.Compose([ T.Resize(256),
    T.CenterCrop(224), T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
train_df, temp_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, stratify=df['label'], random_state=42)  # 80% train, 20% temp
val_df, test_df = train_test_split(temp_df, test_size=0.5, stratify=temp_df['label'], random_state=42)  # 50% val, 50% test
train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
val_df = val_df.reset_index(drop=True)
test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print("TRAIN Dataset: {}".format(train_df.shape))
print("VALIDATION Dataset: {}".format(val_df.shape))
print("TEST Dataset: {}".format(test_df.shape))
train_df_2=Dataset(images=train_df['file_path'].values,labels=train_df['label'].values,transform=transform_my_train)
val_df_2=Dataset(images=val_df['file_path'].values,labels=val_df['label'].values,transform=transform_my)
test_df_2=Dataset(images=test_df['file_path'].values,labels=test_df['label'].values,transform=transform_my)

train_params = {'batch_size': 4,
                'shuffle': True,
                'num_workers': 0,
                'pin_memory':True
                }

test_params = {'batch_size': 4,
                'shuffle': True,
                'num_workers': 0,
               'pin_memory':True
                }
Validation_params = {'batch_size': 4,
                'shuffle': True,
                'num_workers': 0,
                     'pin_memory':True
                }
training_loader = DataLoader(train_df_2, **train_params)
testing_loader = DataLoader(test_df_2, **test_params)
validation_loader = DataLoader(val_df_2, **Validation_params)

import timm

# Load the pretrained model
model = timm.create_model('seresnet50', pretrained=True)
class resnet50_se(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(resnet50_se, self).__init__()
    self.resnet =model
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(0.3)
    self.fc1=torch.nn.Linear(1000,3)
  def forward(self,x):
    x=self.resnet(x)
    x=F.relu(x)
    x=self.dropout(x)
    x = F.softmax(self.fc1(x), dim=1)
    return x
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import CyclicLR
class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
# Creating the loss function and optimizer
loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params =my_resnet50_se.parameters(), lr=0.01,weight_decay=1e-3 )
#sched = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR(optimizer, 0.001, epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=len(training_loader))
Epoch 11/50, Training Loss: 1.0832, Validation Loss: 1.0850
Training F1 Scores: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.7186858316221766}, Validation F1 Scores: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.7213114754098361}
Training Macro F1: 0.2396, Validation Macro F1: 0.2404 


As you can see, the model's performance dropped significantly, especially in its ability to learn the underrepresented classes. I was surprised by this outcome, as I initially expected that adding an SE block would only improve the model. Could the performance drop be due to the imbalanced dataset? With more benign images than normal and malignant ones, it’s possible that during the Excitation phase, channels responsible for the minority classes (normal and malignant) received lower attention, resulting in poorer representation for these classes.
